# Computer screen goes black accessing network folders

Tags: windows-7, networking, shared-folders

We have a computer on our network whose screen goes black when you try to access shared folders on the network.

When working locally it doesn't happen at all. But if you, for instance, open the run command and type in `\\servername` and click **OK** it'll flash black. Or if you open a file in one of the shared folders on that server.

This is a new one for me. Any ideas on how I could begin troubleshooting? I've verified that the *only* time it happens is when accessing files/folders shared on the server and that it *only* happens on that machine.

Comment: Does it do it regardless of the user who's logged into the machine?  does it do the same thing if you login in Safe Mode with Networking? have you updated the network and video adapter drivers to the latest versions available?